# What are the changes/updates to be made in iis7 to host a ASP.NET signalR app?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

What are the changes/updates to be made in iis7 to host a ASP.NET signalR app?

My app works fine in VS2012. When I try to host it in my production server(iis7),
it says the following error in browser console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.mydomain.com/signalr/hubs
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

I tried all the workarounds found in stack overflow...

Comment: have set the default page/Start page for your apllication

Comment: Hard to even suggest anything without any code and "I tried all the workarounds found in stack overflow...". If you've truly tried "all the workarounds" then clearly there's something unique about your setup and you've provided nothing that would help anyone to diagnose what that might be.

Comment: Do you have a reference to SignalR.AspNet.dll?

Comment: Have you looked here? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. I tried the workarounds mentioned at this link https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq .I stll get a 404 error message. I also installed the windows updates for my server.Still not working.. Should I install anything additional on my server (wondows server 2008) to make it signalR ready?

Comment: @Pete I have reference to SignalR.AspNet.dll.I was trying to host the sample chat app mentioned at this tutorial http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr    .It works fine in VS2012.But when I host the project in my production server , it gives 404 error for http://www.mydomain.com/signalr/hubs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on webforms, Please take the following steps

1. In the webconfig:

   ```html
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   ```
2. In the page add reference to hub as

   ```html
   <script src="/signalr/signalr/hubs"></script>
   ```

   instead of

   ```html
   <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Please see this forum for the latest issues:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2242